# Regex to capture blocks of text after certain tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have HTML like this:

```
<h3>What to bring</h3>
<p><p>It's important to bring good walking shoes.  You never know when you will be out walking and there's a decent chance of rain.</p></p>
<h3>How to get there</h3>
It is reachable by many ways: it lies in the visually stunning nature park.
<h3>What not to forget</h3>
Walking shoes!
```

How can I split this in Rails into descriptions and content.  The description is based on the h3 tags.

I already got a regex to extract the titles:

```
description.scan(/<h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/).flatten
```

But how can I extract the content of each block?  So basically I'm looking for an array of 3 blocks of text like this:

```
["<p><p>It's important to bring good walking shoes.  You never know when you will be out walking and there's a decent chance of rain.</p></p>","It is reachable by many ways: it lies in the visually stunning nature park.","Walking shoes!"]
```

The blocks of text can span multiple lines.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `scan` with `split`? Also, remove `(` and `)` if you do not want to have those captures inside the resulting array when using `split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` on this regex:

```
description.split(/<h3>.*?<\/h3>/)
# => [
 "\n<p><p>It's important to bring good walking shoes.  You never know when you will be out walking and there's a decent chance of rain.</p></p>\n",
 "\nIt is reachable by many ways: it lies in the visually stunning nature park.\n",
 "\nWalking shoes!\n"]
```

Assure to remove capturing group form inside the tags.

See the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-split):

> `split(pattern=nil, [limit]) → an_array`
>
> Divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings.
>
> (...)
>
> If pattern is a Regexp, str is divided where the pattern matches. Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, str is split into individual characters. If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.

Comment: You can also use `strip` or `squish` to remove the additional `\n`

Comment: That is absolutely perfect!